# Минуты в формате

Tags: java, datetime

У меня есть запись в БД в минутах. Еще есть стринг в котором хранится формат вывода. Дело в том что я буду его менять, поэтому я припускаю такой вариант:

```
format: "%y%годов %M%месяцев %w%недель %d%дней %h%часов %m%минут"
```

Мне нужно заменить все что в %% на соответствующие числа и вывести. Вопрос как?

Comment: А почему бы вам не распарсить ваш же формат? Он несложный.

Comment: И кстати, вы подумали о том, что может быть "1 минута", но "2 минуты"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему никто не предлагает честный парсер? Мой основан на примере из [документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
static String GetDatePart(char format, Calendar date) {
    switch (format) {
        case 'd': return Integer.toString(date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        // для месяца надо прибавить 1 из-за странностей стандартной библиотеки
        case 'm': return Integer.toString(1 + date.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        case 'y': return Integer.toString(date.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        // и т. д.
        default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown format specifier");
    }
}

static String FormatDate(CharSequence s, Calendar date) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("%(.)%");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s.length());
    while (m.find()) {
        char format = m.group(1).charAt(0);
        String text = GetDatePart(format, date);
        m.appendReplacement(sb, text);
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/teK99u

Перевод минут в `Calendar`, думаю, проблем не составит.

---

Вот пересчёт общего количества минут в недели, дни, часы и минуты:

```
int tempTotalHours = totalMinutes / 60;
int minutes = totalMinutes % 60;

int tempTotalDays = tempTotalHours / 24;
int hours = tempTotalHours % 24;

int totalWeeks = tempTotalDays / 7;
int days = tempTotalDays % 7;
```

Переменные с именами, начинающимися с `temp`, временные.

Вы можете обобщить этот код на случай секунд или миллисекунд. Кстати, эта процедура очень напоминает разложение числа в записи по [смешанной системе счисления](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.A1.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.88.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D1.81.D0.B8.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BC.D1.8B_.D1.81.D1.87.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F).

Comment: Вы не правильно меня поняли. То, что вы написали мне не нужно. Мне нужно перевести минуты в годы, месяцы, недели, дни, часы и минуты. То-есть например 100000 минут это допустим 30y 7M 3w 4d 22h 17m.

То-есть по максимум скоротить

Comment: @AlexWells: Так это самая лёгкая и очевидная часть. `Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); long millis = minutes * 60 * 1000; c.setTimeInMillis(millis);`

Comment: @AlexWells: Из `Calendar` уже легко вытащить год, месяц и всё такое.

Comment: Да нет. Это возвратит мне допустим 100к минут просто поделит на дни. Вот и все. А мне нужно СКОРОТИТЬ! 
То-есть например 100000 минут это допустим 30y 7M 3w 4d 22h 17m. То-есть по максимум скоротить

Comment: Очевидно, как я понял, вы хотите получить "продолжительность" периода, который у вас уже указан в минутах, в годах, месяцах и и т.д. Вас не смущают високосные года, переводы на зимнее-летнее время когда продолжительность суток может быть больше или меньше на час и т.п.?

Comment: @IgorKudryashov: Это вы мне? Если да, то «продолжительность» в годах/месяцах/неделях невозможна в отрыве от начальной даты, именно так. Поэтому я привожу решение для `Calendar`, который должен правильно обрабатывать эти случаи.

Comment: @IgorKudryashov: Например, период между 28 января и 28 февраля — это один месяц? А период между 29 января и 1 марта? А между 1 февраля и 1 марта?

Comment: @VladD, извините, мой вопрос был адресован к Alex Wells

Comment: @IgorKudryashov: Угу, я так и понял, просто переспросил на всякий случай.

Comment: @VladD: Ребят.. я не знаю о чем вы, но:
Есть 10 минут. Они должны вывестись как 0y:0M:0w:0d:0h:10m. (4 суток = 5760 минут). Есть 5934 минуты. Они должны вывестись как 0y:0M:0w:4d:2h:54m. Поняли?

Comment: @Alex Wells, мы о том, что "Сколько дней в вашем году?", "Сколько дней в вашем месяце?", "Сколько часов в ваших сутках?". Ведь все эти числа не всегда постоянны.

Comment: @VladD: Какая разница? Взять месяц за 30 дней, год за 365 дней. И все.

Comment: Если месяц — это 30 дней, то 12 месяцев — это 360 дней. 361 день как хотите выводить?

Comment: Ладно. Я не подумал. Ну хорошо, тогда хотя бы до недель скоротить можно?

Comment: Ну, смотрите. Общее к-во часов = минуты / 60, остаточное количество минут = минуты % 60. Далее, общее к-во дней = общее к-во часов / 24, остаточное к-во часов = общее к-во часов % 24. Далее, общее к-во недель = общее к-во дней / 7, остаточное к-во дней  = общее к-во дней % 7.

Comment: @Alex Wells, посмотите [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), там есть классы Period и Duration. Какой-то вам обязательно подойдёт.

Comment: @IgorKudryashov Спасибо, но я не хочу использовать сторонние библиотеки. Лучше свое, пусть и плохое. Но свое.

Comment: @VladD Спасибо. Вот это как-раз то, что я хотел. Извиняюсь за неправильное выражение в мейн посте :)

Comment: @AlexWells: Окей, тогда я перенесу код из комментария в основной ответ. // Пожалуйста!

Comment: @AlexWells: обновил ответ.